# opening c++ txt file and reading individual digits into int array

Tags: c++, fstream

I am trying to read a text file into an array of integers but my read doesn't affect anything and my array stays at its default value of 0, my code is as follows

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ofstream myfile;
    int a[1000] = {0};
    myfile.open ("Euler7.txt", ios::out | ios::app | ios::binary);

    for (int i=0;i<1000;i++)
    {
        myfile << a[i];
        cout << a[i] << endl;
    }

    myfile.close();

    int c = 0;
    for (int b=0;b>995;b++)
    {
        if (a[b]*a[b+1]*a[b+2]*a[b+3]*a[b+4] > c)
            c = a[b]*a[b+1]*a[b+2]*a[b+3]*a[b+4];
    }

    cout << c << a[0];

    return 0;
}
```

i suspect i need an fin.ignore somewhere in there somewhere, but my skills with files go about as far as #include , the file i am trying to open goe something like

```
6717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318
```

No spaces or separation between numbers. i need each item of the array to hold an individual digit, there are 1000 numbers in the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file stream object is an `ofstream`, which is for writing out to a file. Instead, you want `ifstream`, which is for input. You'll also want to get rid of the `ios::out` and `ios::app` flags in the call to `open`. In addition, you're using operator `<<` which is for output, rather than `>>` for input.

Comment: i had that originally but i received a compiler error (no match for 'operator>>' in 'myfile >> a[i]') so i thought that it was incorrect

Comment: but then, i changed my ofstream to ifstream and that solved it, thanks!

Comment: @user24658 Good. I know it's too early to do it, but since you're new to the site, please remember to accept the answer when you can. :)

Comment: i know that, but i can't accept for 3 minutes, i have used code review before.

Comment: That solved it... really? Are you sure it didn't just solve one  compiler error and leave you with a program that builds but doesn't work?

Comment: i'm working on the string to int conversion right now, then i'm going to convert it to individual digits, but i don't want to bother for anymore help if i don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the fstream technique wasn't needed at all to solve this problem. Special thanks to Tacet for parts of this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;



int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  int pause;
  string series="7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";
  unsigned int max = 0; //if it can not be less than zero, use a unsigned type
  const unsigned int end = series.size()-4;
  for (int i=0;i<end;i++)
  if ((series[i]-'0')*(series[i+1]-'0')*(series[i+2]-'0')*(series[i+3]-'0')*(series[i+4]-'0') > max)
max = (series[i]-'0')*(series[i+1]-'0')*(series[i+2]-'0')*(series[i+3]-'0')*(series[i+4]-'0');
  cout << max << '\n';


    cin >> pause;
    return 0;
}
```